# c# calculate data from sql

Tags: c#, sql, calculation

I'm currently developing an import module to import data from csv to our database.
In one file that I receive from an external package, I receive data which I need to add to the already existing data.

For example in the database there are salesnumbers for week1, week2, ...
In the file that I receive, I only receive the extra sales that have been done for week1, week2, ...
So I have to add week1 from the database with week1 from the csv file. The sum then needs to be written to the database.

There are always 53 weeks in the csv file and 53 weeks in the database, so that's fixed.
What is the best and fastest approach to get the existing data, add the new data and return the sum to the database?

Snip of the csv file
[image]

Snip of the database
[image]

So the value of the csv needs to be added to the existing value for that week in the database.

Comment: This can be as simple as running `UPDATE` SQL Command on the database table or as complex as writing lot of C# and SQL code. and that depends what type of table structure and csv file structure you have....and those are not clear from your question. so it is very difficult to provide a solution for your issues... Can you share some details around how the database table look like and how the csv file look like? you need to share the code you have written to solve this issue and also explain what's the the issue you are facing.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you use for read the CSV file? for example [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/). And to write to the database? You can read the value from the database, add the value from the CSV file and write back to the database.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have added 2 snips, 1 from the csv and 1 from the sql

Comment: And you will match the row using `Article` from CSV and `Artikelnummer` from the database table?

Comment: @polkduran I just do it with ReadAllLines from the files given, no extra tools, just developed code

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yeah article and artikelnummer, but also branch and vestiging. It's a double match

Comment: So this looks like nothing more complicated than loading the CSV file into a staging table and then having an `update` that will join from the staging table to the Sales table using he two key columns and updating each column and adding the new values to the existing values. That assumes the CSV data only contains 1 row per branch/article?

Comment: @Stu Yeah only 1 row per branch/article. I think I'm no longer seeing clearly how to do it. Since I think that I will need to get every week from the database (select every week) and add it with the new data from that week.

Comment: Assuming the table's primary key is also a composite of branch/article. You will just need to write an `update` statement, updating each column. The design really should have weeks as rows, it would be much easier to manage then! Fortunately you have one column per week and not per day... How does this design cater for years?

Comment: I agree with you.   There are 4 steps 1) Read CSV file 2) Read Database 3) Add value from CSV file to old values 4) Store results back to database.  If you use Entity or Read Data using a DataAdaptor The last step would be to use an update method which is oneinstruction.

Comment: @stu every year the weeks are reset, I get the year from the filename that I receive from the external package. Since this external package is limited with the possibilities that I have to receive data (old ERP system written in COBOL), I'm doing as much as possible to transform data into an SQL database to finally be able to analyse our data.

Comment: I would suggest the most efficient way of implementing this would be having a procedure in the database that you call as the final step after running the import process to load the data into its staging table.

Comment: @stu thanks, I think I found a possible solution with using a staging table